# How can I get my function to display over an image (and retain the image)?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to coding and having a few issues. I'm trying to input text into a html form field (button) which will then be displayed on the same page over an image. The two now seemed to be linked but new text appears as an overlay.  How can I reset this to enable a change of customisation? Also my image has disappeared, is there anything obvious that would have caused this?

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="600" style="border:1px solid #404040;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas><script>


function myFunction() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img =new Image(); 


img.onload = function() {



ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 900, 600);

}
//the code below positions the overlaying text on the image
ctx.font = "bold 36px Times";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillText ( document.getElementById("line1").value ,400,325);
ctx.fillText ( document.getElementById("line2").value ,400,375);
ctx.fillText ( document.getElementById("line3").value ,400,425);
}

//this is the image 
img.src= "bus_red.gif"</script>

//the code below allows the user to input text into boxes

<div>
<form>
<label for="line1">Enter your text: </label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="line1" placeholder="line1"><br>
<label for="line2">Enter your text: </label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="line2" placeholder="line2"><br>
<label for="line3">Enter your text: </label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="line3" placeholder="line3"><br>


<input type="radio" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</input> 
</form></div>
```

Comment: `img.src= "bus_red.gif"` needs to be inside of the function

Comment: Thank you, I've tried changing the positions of the brackets but the bus still isn't appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `img.src` needs to be declared inside of the function. The variable `img` can only be accessed and manipulated inside of the function. Second, the `fillText` functions must be inside of the `onload` function. The image loads *after* the text is written. The text takes a microsecond or two to be written while the image takes a millisecond to load.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = new Image();


  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 900, 600);
    //the code below positions the overlaying text on the image
    ctx.font = "bold 36px Times";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("line1").value, 400, 325);
    ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("line2").value, 400, 375);
    ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("line3").value, 400, 425);
  }
  img.src = "https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg"
}

//this is the image
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="600" style="border:1px solid #404040;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>



<div>
  <form>
    <label for="line1">Enter your text: </label>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="line1" placeholder="line1"><br>
    <label for="line2">Enter your text: </label>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="line2" placeholder="line2"><br>
    <label for="line3">Enter your text: </label>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="line3" placeholder="line3"><br>


    <input type="radio" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</input>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job. Try it, replace the image link.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="600" style="border:1px solid #404040;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas><script>


function myFunction() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img =new Image(); 

img.src= "images/image2.jpg"
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 900, 600);
//the code below positions the overlaying text on the image
ctx.font = "bold 36px Times";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";

ctx.fillText ( document.getElementById("line1").value ,400,325);
ctx.fillText ( document.getElementById("line2").value ,400,375);
ctx.fillText ( document.getElementById("line3").value ,400,425);
}

function myFunction2() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
//this is the image 
</script>

//the code below allows the user to input text into boxes

<div>
<form>
<label for="line1">Enter your text: </label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="line1" placeholder="line1"><br>
<label for="line2">Enter your text: </label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="line2" placeholder="line2"><br>
<label for="line3">Enter your text: </label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="line3" placeholder="line3"><br>


<input type="radio" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</input> 
<a href="#" id="input-reset" onclick="myFunction2()">Reset</a>
</form></div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not coming up, still trying a few things, need the picture back under the fillText.

Comment: Can you try to double click on the "click me" button and try to see if the image appears.

If you insert the image below the fillText, it will only display the display over the text.

And if you put it before the fillText, it will display the image first and then the fillText value above the image.

Comment: I still have no image. Tried everything I can think of.

Comment: I'm really sorry, still no image